# scroll bar on div with overflow:auto and percentage height

Tags: html, scroll, height, overflow, percentage

Is it possible to create a div that adjusts to the size of the browser and is also scrollable?
I want to use `overflow:auto` on the div and percentage height of `90%`.

The structure of the page is

```
<body style="height:100%">
<div id=header style="height:100%">headerinfo</div>
<div id=content style="height:100%;overflow:auto">content which is replaced dynamically</div>
</body>
```

Will `overflow:auto` work without a known `px` height somewhere in the hierarchy?

Comment: I am amazed ! id=header works ! (without quotation marks). Seems crazy that a DOM tag can be used as an ID…

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In answer to your question, yes `overflow:auto` will work, but you will need `height: 100%` on the HTML tag as well:

```
html,body {    
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#header {
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The way your markup is structured though will produce two divs both the same height as the viewport one on top of the other. Is that what you intended?

If so here is a jsFiddle that illustrates your example. I've tweaked the markup and added additional content so that the content div overflows as you require.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/WsNjm/