# Designing 3 row html layout

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to design a layout where i will have header 100px at the top. footer 80px always stick to the bottom of browser screen and an scrollable content area in between header and footer. the vertical scrollbar should come in the content area when i finished writing till the content touches the top end of footer.

Can Anyone suggest me how can i achieve this

Here is what i have tried: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmMeg/)

```
<header>
</header>
<div id="main">
<div id="content">
scrollable content area
</div>
<footer>
footer always appearing bottom of the browser screen
</footer>
</div>
```

My css:

```
header {
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
background: #bbb;
}
#main {
background: #ccc;
width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
#content {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: green;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
footer {
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
background: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: I've added a solution for you using pure JavaScript. I think this will the best cross-browser answer for you at the moment. I've also included resize code when browser is resized.

Comment: [something you might want to look at](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/)

Comment: @user2786485 Please check the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:** <kbd>[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalkin/dm4DA/2/)</kbd>

```
#content {
position: absolute;
height: calc(100% - 180px);
background: green;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: can you just make the scrollbar to appear inside the content area. i don't want it over the body.

Comment: @user2847429 For that you have to use javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Just tell me what you have tried? I don't see any header, any footer, just a text there in the scollable div.

Ok let me guide you a bit.

What you do is simple but would require you to understand the point.

#### How to make the footer stick to the bottom.

```
footer {
 position: absolute; // position as absolute..
 bottom: 0; // margin-bottom as 0 
 max-width: 80px; // width
 margin: 0 auto; // margin..
}
```

This will make the footer to always stay at the end of the document I mean at the bottom of the page.

#### How to make header

```
header {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 max-width: 100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

#### How to make a scrollable div

**I donot fully understand this one**. So I am just going to guide you a bit.

You can create a scrollbar in the content div. You want this:

> the vertical scrollbar should come in the content area

You can do that by using this:

```
div {
 max-height: 100px;
 min-height: 100px;
}
```

I will assume that you are going to change the `div` to the element or class or id to the one you're having.

#### Making a scrollable div with a scrollbar.

First you will create a div with a max-height, to make the div not exceed the height of the screen. Then you can use a scrollbar like this:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Add this property to the element. This way, you'll have a footer, an header, and a content block which has a scrollbar for it self, not the one that browser has.

#### Fiddle for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/aNRE9/2/

I am really sorry but I didn't bother changing the background, but you can see, the header stays there, footer at the end, and the div scrolls! :)

Good luck!

Comment: For your `margin:0 auto;` would this make the item stick to the bottom of the HTML Document or the bottom of the window? I ask out of curiosity :)

Comment: i want the exact layout like we are having in gmail. we have scrollable content area where our mails are shown.

Comment: margin has nothing to do with the stickness brother! The stickness will be made by `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` as far as the margin is concerned, margin would work perfectly. If you mean the margin will change its position then you're wrong it won't `margin: 0 auto` means no margin vertically and browser should choose one horizontaly @Nunners

Comment: That need 20 developers working along or 20 hours for yourself. Ok, that is the same one, you are just creating a div and setting its height to a max of the screen height and then adding `overflow: scroll;`

Comment: I just added `overflow: scroll` and added a few words to get it to work :) That was simple, you can change the background hehehe

Comment: He wants the header to stick there too. You're fiddle is a bit wrong :( He wants to add the scroll bar to the div only not the whole document.

Comment: i didnot understand one thing. all the content is written in p tag. then why half of the content background is in green.

Comment: because the `content` id is having green background, not the `p`.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question before at: [Div height percentage based but still scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118277/div-height-percentage-based-but-still-scrolling)

Here is one approach.

The HTML:

```
<header>The Header...</header>
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        scrollable content area
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...</p>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>footer always appearing bottom of the browser screen</footer>
```

The CSS:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body { 
    margin: 0;
}
header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #bbb;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#main {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 80px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#content {
    overflow: auto;
    background: green;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #aaa;
}
```

The trick is to create an absolutely positioned block container that spans the area between the header and the footer, `#main`, using the top, bottom, left, right offsets, and apply `overflow-y: auto`.

The `#content` will then take up space and eventually trigger the scroll bar on `#main`.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/aNRE9/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JavaScript for this unfortunately. No big deal. I've also added the handler for when you resize the window.

```
var resizeTimer;
window.onload = function(){
    makeMiddleFull();
}

window.onresize = function(){
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(makeMiddleFull, 100);
}
function makeMiddleFull(){
    var cobj = document.getElementById('content');
    cobj.style.height = (getDocHeight() - (document.getElementById('header').style.height + document.getElementById('footer').style.height)) + "px";
}
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight,
        D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
}
```

See updated fiddle for full code updates including DOM and CSS here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Qpc2s/2/

Comment: He don't need that! He just wants a scrollbar in that and just a simple footer and header who stick to their position.

Comment: i want the header to stick to top. i just want the content area to be scrollable